# Where can you find support/status for appengine if you're not a Premier Account?

Tags: google-app-engine

We're a non-Premier account holder on appengine.  We've experienced a couple of episodes where we consistently get 500 errors for about a day and then things clear up.  During these episodes (one is happening now), we check the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-appengine), the [System Status page](http://code.google.com/status/appengine), and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine), but nothing is ever mentioned while we're experiencing the problems.  After the fact, we sometimes see a mention that Google was experiencing some problems around the same time we were (I forget where I saw this mentioned, though).

There doesn't appear to be anywhere to ask if others are experiencing problems except perhaps in the Google Group.  The group seems to have a very low volume of traffic and seems almost unused.

The real questions are these:  Is there any way to get support from Google without having a premier account?  Is there any way to ask if Google is experiencing issues that might be affecting our app(s).  Is there any way to ask others if they are experiencing similar problems.

I've looked and looked, but can't find any place to get this kind of information.  Is it hiding in plain sight?  Any help finding it is very welcome.

Comment: Is you app going over the free quotas? Have you checked your application's dashboard on http://appengine.google.com?

Comment: We are well under the free quotas. I'm not necessarily looking for an answer to the problems we're experiencing right now.  I'd rather find out where we can go for answers about these types of issues when we need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can use the Google Group you mentioned.  There's also a group for downtime notification: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-downtime-notify

You can also file a production issue on the App Engine issues list: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

You get what you pay for I supposed.

Comment: Thanks dragonx.  I believe you are correct.  I hadn't noticed that there is a "fair" amount of activity in the Google Group.  So that's probably the place to ask for help on these issues.

Comment: dragonx, Your link to the issues list was very helpful, too.  I was able to find that our current problem is known and they are looking into it.  This was a very useful exchange.  Thanks again.

Comment: glad to help.  Also, Stack Overflow is the official help forum, so you do see answers from google folks here from time to time (not me),

Comment: This was a general question about how to find answers and information about system status, not about system status at a given time.  This is good information for everyone to be able to find anytime.